# How to get the values by passing id as prefix in the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the values of the variable by passing the ID as prefix.

```
    console.log(STUDENT_7); //Output: all JSON values
    console.log($("STUDENT_", id)); //not printing.
    console.log("STUDENT_"+id)); //Output: Student_7.
```

Not sure if it is possible to get the values with the prefix.

To get all JSON values.

Comment: You'd be better off storing your `STUDENT_n` properties in an object instead of having them as scoped variables

Comment: defining it as let STUDENT_{!! $student->id !!} = {!! $student !!}; Do I need to change something here?

Comment: Try something like `const students = { {!! $student->id !!}: {!! $student !!} }`. Then you can more easily use `students[id]`